# Plotting many columns from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Imagine I have a very big csv file with 500 rows and 500 columns. 
Part of the data shown :
[a small section of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya1Ex.png)

I cannot delete the first couple of rows from my file but I can omit them using "skiprows" while reading the file.

Then I want to plot my data and all methods that I try fail. 
I actually get a plot if I just use 'plot()" command but what I want is to have the first column as my x data and the rest of 499 columns as my y data. 
Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Kindly refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Anshul Thanks but not useful at all. I basically teach those things. The problem is that I am new to Python!

Comment: What I wanted to convey is that you need to provide details that can help reproduce the issue - sample input and expected output data in text/copy-pastable format, you attempt with the code to get the solution and the specific error you are getting etc.

Comment: @Dana Welcome to SO. Let me know if you found my post helpful and if it solved your problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your DataFrame and the first column is named `x-data`, then you can plot all other columns vs `x-data` like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.iloc[:i+1,:].plot(x='x-data', ax=ax)
```