# Plotting Multiple Columns Across Rows in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, indexing, numpy-slicing

I have the following process stats that I have captured using Python's psutil (see attached [csv](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/ac97ffed30f5225769e543e99f77f173/process_stats.csv)). I am trying to use Pandas and Matplotlib to slice this dataframe such that I can plot all several processes on the same graph for their cpu-usage. Similarly I wish to do the same for their memory usage.[image: dataframe of process stats]

Comment: This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036205/plotting-many-columns-from-a-csv-file/62050346#62050346) will be helpful to you.

Comment: Screenshots of code don't work here. Please [edit] your question with the code as text.

Comment: @BigBen I wanted to show the python data frame multi-dimensional table with its rows and columns. The code along with it is rudimentary.

Comment: That's *not* how this site works... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask literally says in bold: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to graph the time and memory usage separated by nucleus, you can use the following code

```
process_data['create_time']=pd.to_datetime(process_data['create_time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
process_data.set_index('create_time', inplace=True)

for i in process_data['cores'].unique().tolist():
    process_data['memory_usage'][process_data['cores']==i].plot()
plt.show()
```